# Verificar se existe parâmetro em URL javascript

Tags: javascript, url

Tenho uma URL que poderá ou não conter parâmetros nela. Ex: `www.site.com.br/?id=1` ou `www.site.com.br`.

Preciso verificar se existe algum parametro nesta URL e com isso poder acrescentar mais um no final. Por ex:

- Se URL for `www.site.com.br` vira `www.site.com.br/?id=1`
- Se URL for `www.site.com.br/?utm=teste` vira `www.site.com.br/?utm=teste&id=1`

Ou seja, a URL poderá ou não ter um parâmetro e esse parâmetro poderá ser aleatório, com isso não tenho como saber exatamente qual o parâmetro terei.

Preciso saber isso, pois preciso adicionar um parâmetro `id=SC` no fim da URL e em algumas vezes está dando erro, pois já existe um parâmetro anterior. Veja como estou fazendo:

```
//Pego a url anterior que o usuário estava e redireciono para a mesma url porém adicionando um parametro no final    
window.location.href = document.referrer+'?id=CS';
```

Com o código acima, se a URL anterior for `www.site.com.br/?utm=teste` a nova URL ficará `site.com.br/?utm=teste?id=CS` e o usuário não conseguirá acessar a página.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode verificar com regex se no `document.referrer` possui o padrão:

```
?qualquer_coisa=
```

Se for verdadeiro, concatena `&`, se for falso, concatena `?`:

```
var ref = document.referrer;
window.location.href = ref + (/\?.{1,}=/.test(ref) ? '&' : '?') + 'id=CS';
```

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83013/discussion-on-answer-by-sam-verificar-se-existe-parametro-em-url-javascript)

Answer (score 5):

Basta usar `SearchParams.set()`.

```js
var url="";

//COM parametro id na url, substitui o valor
url = new URL('http://www.site.com.br/?utm=teste&id=12');
   url.searchParams.set('id', 'SC');
    console.log(url.toString());

//SEM parametro id na url, acrescenta o parametro e respectivo valor
// já separado com &
url = new URL('http://www.site.com.br/?utm=teste');
    url.searchParams.set('id', 'SC');
    console.log(url.toString());
    
//SEM parametros na url acrescenta o parametro e respectivo valor
//com a interrogação (?)
url = new URL('http://www.site.com.br');
    url.searchParams.set('id', 'SC');
    console.log(url.toString());

 // com anchor
   url = new URL('http://www.site.com.br/?utm=teste&id=12#secao');
   url.searchParams.set('id', 'SC');
    console.log(url.toString());
```

Comment: É uma solução também, mas não gosto dessas APIs porque não funciona no IEca.

Comment: @sam hahaha, só fazer assim: if(isIE == true){ use o do tio sam}else{use o do vô leo} :)

Answer (score 2):

Uma alternativa é usar [`new URL(endereco)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL) para criar um objeto `URL` e depois usar um [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/URLSearchParams) para manipular os parâmetros da URL.

Através do método `set` é possível adicionar o novo parâmetro. Depois basta atualizá-lo na URL:

```js
// URL sem parâmetros
var url = new URL('http://www.site.com.br');

var sp = new URLSearchParams(url.search);
sp.set('id', '1')
url.search = sp;

console.log(url.toString()); // http://www.site.com.br/?id=1

//--------------------------------------
// URL com parâmetro
url = new URL('http://site.com.br/teste/p?utm=teste');

sp = new URLSearchParams(url.search);
sp.set('id', '1')
url.search = sp;

console.log(url.toString()); // http://site.com.br/teste/p?utm=teste&id=1
```

O detalhe é que o endereço deve ter o protocolo (`http://etc...`, `https://etc...`, `ftp://etc...`), caso contrário `new URL` dá erro - ou seja, `new URL('http://www.abc.com')` e `new URL('https://www.abc.com')` funciona, mas `new URL('www.abc.com')` dá erro.

---

Para manipular a URL atual, você pode fazer `var url = new URL(window.location)`. Depois você adiciona os parâmetros que precisa (usando `set`) e por fim faz `window.location = url`:

```
var url = new URL(window.location);

var sp = new URLSearchParams(url.search);
sp.set('id', '1')
url.search = sp;

window.location = url;
```

---

**Obs:** caso a URL já possua um parâmetro `id`, o `set` sobrescreverá seu valor:

```js
// já tem id=2
var url = new URL('http://www.site.com.br/?id=2');

var sp = new URLSearchParams(url.search);
sp.set('id', '1')
url.search = sp;

// sobrescreve o valor de id para 1
console.log(url.toString()); // http://www.site.com.br/?id=1
```

Se for o caso, você pode verificar se já existe o parâmetro `id` usando `if (sp.has('id'))`

---

Usar regex e adicionar o parâmetro no final pode funcionar para a maioria dos casos, mas se a URL tiver *anchor*, não vai funcionar. Isso porque o *anchor* fica no final (ver [aqui](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-4.2) e [aqui](https://superuser.com/q/498617)).

Por exemplo, se a URL for `http://www.site.com/?teste=1#secao`. Se eu simplesmente adicionar o parâmetro no final, a URL ficará `http://www.site.com/?teste=1#secao&id=1`, o que não é o desejado, já que neste caso o `id=1` não faz parte da *query string*. Usando `URLSearchParams` você obtém o resultado correto, que é `http://www.site.com/?teste=1&id=1#secao`, veja:

```js
// tem anchor "#secao"
var url = new URL('http://www.site.com/?teste=1#secao');

var sp = new URLSearchParams(url.search);
sp.set('id', '1')
url.search = sp;

// adiciona o id na posição correta (antes do anchor)
console.log(url.toString()); // http://www.site.com/?teste=1&id=1#secao
```

Apenas para deixar mais claro a diferença:

```js
// tem anchor "#secao"
var url = new URL('http://www.site.com/?teste=1&id=1#secao');
var sp = new URLSearchParams(url.search);
// imprime teste=1 e id=1
for (var [nome, valor] of sp.entries()) {
    console.log(`${nome}=${valor}`);
}
console.log(url.hash); // #secao

console.log('----------------');
// se adicionar o parâmetro depois do anchor, não funciona
url = new URL('http://www.site.com/?teste=1#secao&id=1');
sp = new URLSearchParams(url.search);
// só vai imprimir teste=1
for (var [nome, valor] of sp.entries()) {
    console.log(`${nome}=${valor}`);
}
// tudo que está depois do # é o anchor
console.log(url.hash); // #secao&id=1
```

Repare que quando a URL é `http://www.site.com/?teste=1#secao&id=1`, somente o `teste` é reconhecido como parâmetro da *query string*. Já tudo que está depois do `#` (no caso, `secao&id=1`) faz parte do *anchor* (ou seja, se apenas concatenar `&id=1` no final da string, este não é reconhecido como parâmetro).

Por isso que concatenar no final não é garantido que funcione em 100% dos casos.

---

Atualmente, esta API funciona bem no Firefox, Chrome, Edge e Safari, mas não no IE 11: https://caniuse.com/#search=URLSearchParams

Comment: Se quiser pegar o domínio dinamicamente também pode usar o `document.domain`, no caso de não querer algo fixo no `new URL`.

Answer (score 1):

Acho que sua própria lógica já indica que o que você precisa fazer é um if. Ex:

```
if(document.referrer.contains("/?")){
window.location.href = document.referrer+'?id=CS'
}
else{
window.location.href = document.referrer+'&id=CS'
}
```

Comment: mas e se a url anterior for por ex: site.com.br/teste/p?utm=teste ou seja, não posso colocar uma regra fixa...poderia pesquisar apenas se existe a "?" na url, mas não sei se seria certo

Comment: Pq a url dessa pagina é amigavel, ou seja, cada uma é de um jeito. Vai que na url amigavel tenha "?" acho dificil, mas vai saber